# wc_get_order does not allow to use variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Hei everybody. Maybe someone could give me some tips , because I am stuck on this for second day.

```
function get_url_id() {
    
    $_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
    $data = $_GET['id'];
    
    $final= xss_clean($data); // function to prevent xss, working 
    
    return $final;
} 


function relax() {
    ;
}

function show_order_details_created_date() {
    
    if( $user = wp_get_current_user() ){
        
        
     $order_id= get_url_id();
     
     if(!isset($order_id)) { relax(); } else {
    $order = wc_get_order ($order_id);

    $date=$order->get_date_created();
    $date_mod=explode("T" , $date);
    return $date_mod[0];
 }
}

}
```

Wordpress is giving me critical error , that I can not even open to edit page section. If instead of $order_id I insert existing order number ITS WORKS ABSOLUTELY fine. If I print out variable it also shows ID without problem. Why I can not use variable here? Any hints, guys?